# how to add an image to md-dialog using id of div Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c3.js, mddialog

I want to bind the c3chart id to div id present in md-dialog. But when I try to get the div id by document.getElementById it returns null to me. I dont know what I'm missing. I'm new to angularjs and not able to find out the cause chart not binding to div id.

Below the html template I'm trying to load for the dialog :

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Export Image" ng-cloak>
    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h2>Export Image</h2>
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
                <md-icon aria-label="Close dialog">close</md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
     <md-content layout-padding>
      <div class='legend2'></div> 
       <div id="chart"></div>
      <div class='legend1'></div>  
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
        <md-button md-menu-origin ng-click="exportToPng()">
          <span>Save as PNG</span>   
        </md-button>
        <md-button md-menu-origin ng-click="exportToSvg()">
          <span>Save as SVG</span>   
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-content>
</md-dialog>
```

Below is the service I'm using to load md-dialog on clicking the image export button:

```
$mdDialog.show({
   controller: 'ExportImagesDisplayCtrl',
   templateUrl: templateUrl,
   parent: angular.element(document.body),
   targetEvent: ev,
   locals: {
        stats: stats,
        filterKey: filterKey,
        filterType: filterType
   },
   clickOutsideToClose: true
});
```

Below is the part of the controller where I'm trying to bind the chart to div id:

```
$scope.drawC3Chart = function(chartGroup){
     var element = document.getElementById("chart");
     var chart = c3.generate({ 
                    bindto: element,
                    size: {
                            height: 235,
                            width: 330
                    },
                    data: {
                        type: 'bar',
                        json: chartGroup,
                        keys: {
                            x:'name',
                            value: ['to', 'from'],
                        }
                    },
                    axis: {
                        x:{
                            type:'category',
                            label: {
                                text: 'from/to',
                                position: 'outer-center'
                            }
                        },
                        y:{
                            label: {
                                text: 'count',
                                position: 'outer-middle'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    grid: {
                        y: {
                            show: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        show: false
                    },
                    regions: [
                                {axis: 'x', end: 1.5 , class:'regionX2'},
                                {axis: 'x', start: 1.5, end: 6, class:'regionX1' },
                             ]
                });
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense needing to look it up in the DOM. Why can't you pass a scope model value to `locals`? Or pass an argument string to `exportToPng`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must access to 'chart' element after dialog load progress complete or use **$timeout** instead:

```
$mdDialog.show({
   controller: 'ExportImagesDisplayCtrl',
   templateUrl: templateUrl,
   parent: angular.element(document.body),
   targetEvent: ev,
   locals: {
        stats: stats,
        filterKey: filterKey,
        filterType: filterType
   },
   clickOutsideToClose: true,
   onComplete: function(){
      $scope.drawC3Chart(); // <---- TODO: draw your chart at here
   }
});
```

Comment: thank you it works but with a delay. Is there way we to reduce the delay ?

Comment: No, I suggest a show loading gif preloader to user until dialog load & chart drawing complete